# Auto align vertically when width decreases

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have three buttons aligned like below when the width of the container is 640px:
**UIButton 1** <30px> **UIButton 2** <30px> **UIButton 3**

When the width decreases to 320px, I would like to bring the third button to the next line like this:

**UIButton 1** <30px> **UIButton 2** 
**UIButton 3**

Let me know if this can be done using autolayout **without** creating outlets of the constraints.

Comment: you will have to incorporate size classes as well to solve it

Comment: Thanks. But size classes would be my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a collection view with a left aligned vertical flow layout. It may seem a bit of an overkill but works nice.

Answer (score 0):

You are must overide `layoutSubviews` and recalculate manualy `setFrame`'s  properties for each views.

I found this [blog post](http://devetc.org/code/2014/07/07/auto-layout-and-views-that-wrap.html) with example on [github](https://github.com/jmah/WrapDemo)

Answer (score 0):

Because there wasn't any specification about how/where to create such constraints I'd go this way.

Here is a little [NSLayoutConstraint Extension](https://bit.ly/1iP4gjJ) of mine to create constraints fast (for iOS 9 and later).

I'm not using StoryBoards/IB so here is a fast code solution in Swift (2.0):

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    private let button1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    private let button2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    private let button3 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)

    private var buttonArray: [UIButton] { return [self.button1, self.button2, self.button3] }

    private var constraintsForWideWidth: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    private var constraintsForShortWidth: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // set your buttons somewhere !!!

        self.view.addSubview(self.button1)
        self.view.addSubview(self.button2)
        self.view.addSubview(self.button3)

        self.setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {

        // points are doubled px on retina display
        // setup the width and/or height as you would like
        // for this example I'll set them with some static numbers

        for button in self.buttonArray {

            NSLayoutConstraint.with(button.widthAnchor == 80)
            NSLayoutConstraint.with(button.heightAnchor == 20)
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.with(self.button2.leftAnchor == self.button1.rightAnchor, constant: 15)
        NSLayoutConstraint.with(self.button2.centerYAnchor == self.button1.centerYAnchor)

        self.constraintsForWideWidth.append(NSLayoutConstraint.with(self.button3.leftAnchor == self.button2.rightAnchor, constant: 15))
        self.constraintsForWideWidth.append(NSLayoutConstraint.with(self.button3.centerYAnchor == self.button2.centerYAnchor))

        self.constraintsForShortWidth.append(NSLayoutConstraint.with(self.button3.topAnchor == self.button1.bottomAnchor, active: false))
        self.constraintsForShortWidth.append(NSLayoutConstraint.with(self.button3.centerXAnchor == self.button1.centerXAnchor, active: false))
    }

    func someFunctionThatExecutesWhenTheSizeChanges() {

        // deactivate both, because we want less code later
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraintsForShortWidth)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraintsForWideWidth)
        // 640 px are 320 pt
        if self.view.frame.width == 320 {

            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsForWideWidth)

        } else if self.view.frame.width == 160 {

            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsForShortWidth)
        }

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Don't be afraid of the code, it is not that much and really not that hard to understand. :) Hope that will help you somehow.